# Heroku and Sqlite3 problems

Tags: deployment, heroku, sqlite, github

Trying to deploy a very basic rails app to Heroku. It runs on sqlite3, and I've had some problems getting it to deploy.

First, I made sure the gem listed sqlite3 under development. That got the index page to finally work, but now when I deploy it and try to follow the links to the part of the page that actually relies on my database, heroku errors. I stared at the logs for a bit and have no idea what's going on, so I was hoping someone here might. I'll just post the log for what appears to be the last action (following the link) for now:

```
2012-09-13T01:00:23+00:00 heroku[router]: GET bloc-blog-1.herokuapp.com/ dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=187ms status=200 bytes=531
2012-09-13T01:00:24+00:00 heroku[router]: GET bloc-blog-1.herokuapp.com/assets/application-0149f820dbdd285aa65e241569d8c256.css dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=9ms status=200 bytes=811
2012-09-13T01:00:24+00:00 heroku[router]: GET bloc-blog-1.herokuapp.com/assets/application-1c74ddb87f4b5b3c36c58d068d148c95.js dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=9ms status=200 bytes=99469
2012-09-13T01:00:27+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-09-13T01:00:27+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-09-13T01:00:27+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/posts" for 50.131.223.42 at 2012-09-13 01:00:27 +0000
2012-09-13T01:00:27+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PostsController#index as HTML
2012-09-13T01:00:27+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 75ms
2012-09-13T01:00:27+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-09-13T01:00:27+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 4:              WHERE a.attrelid = '"posts"'::regclass
2012-09-13T01:00:27+00:00 app[web.1]:                                         ^
2012-09-13T01:00:27+00:00 app[web.1]: :             SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod), d.adsrc, a.attnotnull
2012-09-13T01:00:27+00:00 app[web.1]:               FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
2012-09-13T01:00:27+00:00 app[web.1]: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "posts" does not exist
2012-09-13T01:00:27+00:00 app[web.1]:                 ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
2012-09-13T01:00:27+00:00 app[web.1]:              WHERE a.attrelid = '"posts"'::regclass
2012-09-13T01:00:27+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
2012-09-13T01:00:27+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-09-13T01:00:27+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:5:in `index'
2012-09-13T01:00:27+00:00 app[web.1]:                AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
2012-09-13T01:00:27+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-09-13T01:00:27+00:00 app[web.1]:              ORDER BY a.attnum
2012-09-13T01:00:27+00:00 heroku[router]: GET bloc-blog-1.herokuapp.com/posts dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=86ms status=500 bytes=643
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku uses PostgreSQL. Follow the instructions in the [Rails Tutorial Book](http://railstutorial.org) to install PostgreSQL locally so that you can duplicate the Heroku DB environment.  [Heroku itself](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/how-do-i-use-sqlite3-for-development) and also just about every tutorial warn that developing in sqlite3 then deploying to PostgreSQL is fraught with peril.

Comment: I'm no expert on Heroku internals, but the message is pretty clear.  The error is in a.attrelid = '"posts"'::regclass .  This is junk for SQL.  The PostgreSQL ActiveRecord implementation is creating the syntax '"posts"'::regclass, which is meaningless to the SQL parser.  Without your code it's impossible to say more.

Comment: Huh. Where in my code might the problem be? I don't know where to start looking. (And I did, as suggested include the pg gem as in railstutorial.org).

Comment: The other confusing thing is this is pretty much all scaffolding. I didn't change much at all, and it works perfectly on the local server.

Comment: Huh indeed, or maybe duh... app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:5:in `index' .  Of course I don't have that line.  I say again, if you are running sqlite3 locally, then working perfectly on the local machine implies nothing about running on Heroku.  The instructions for installing PG are pretty simple. It takes about 1/2 hour.  You've probably already used that much time typing to me ;-)

Comment: Right. As I said above, I installed PG. (And pushed to git, and pushed to heroku again). It took like 5 minutes, but it didn't fix anything. Whatever. The error line in posts_controller is scaffold-generated, which is what's primarily confusing, because rails out-of-the-box scaffolds shouldn't cause errors, right? At any rate, thanks.

Comment: Did you change your config so that PG is being used in the local installation?  If you didn't, then your development is still using sqlite3.  The point is you have to reproduce the bug on the local machine so that you can debug under your control. Rails is pretty complex under the hood.  It's pretty easy to break assumptions of scaffold code so that it dies.  If you put your code in a public git repo and provide a pointer I will try to look at it tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks so much for offering. This was just me testing out rails by following a tutorial, though, so I'll let it be and re-confront the problem if it comes up again later, when I'm more comfortable with rails and can debug better myself. Don't worry about it. Again, really appreciate the offer, though. Thanks for the help.